# SOQL query to pull cases that has openactivities

Tags: soql

I am trying to pull list of cases in workbench that has open activities and my query is :

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Subject, Status, Priority, OwnerId FROM OpenActivities) FROM case
```

The above query pulls all the cases irrespective of they have openactivities or not. Can someone please guide me how to add a where clause here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Inner SOQL for same would be as below

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Subject, Status, Priority, OwnerId FROM OpenActivities) FROM case where Id IN (Select WhatId from OpenActivity)
```

**But kindly note Inner SOQL is not supported and hence you cant do this without further using if clause in apex**

```
 list<Case> lst=[ SELECT Id, (SELECT Subject, Status, Priority, OwnerId FROM OpenActivities) FROM case];

 list<Case> lstcasewithopenActivities=new  list<Case>();
 for(Case c:lst){
    if(c.OpenActivities.size()>0){
       lstcasewithopenActivities.add(c);
    }
 }
```

Another approach is to write some code to keep the count on Case record when an activity is created or edited

Some sample code already written in below blog if that helps you

http://rjpalombo.com/2013/11/counting-open-activities-salesforce/

Comment: Hi Mohith, Thanks for your reply. So just to confirm, there is no way to filter cases in workbench that have no open activities, right ?

Comment: Atlesst not I am aware of